# Why am I getting Unexpected token [ in the following for...of loop?

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, ecmascript-6

What the code does is to take a string and replace the content inside using a `regex` and a `replacement`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict'

function massReplace(text, replacementArray) {
  let results = text
  for (let [regex, replacement] of replacementArray) {
    results = results.replace(regex, replacement)
  }
  return results
}

function transformHeadings() {
  let text = `# Title

## Title`

  massReplace(text,
    [ [ /\*\*([^\*|\s]+)\*\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>'], 
    [ /\*([^\*|\s]+)\*/g,       '<em>$1</em>' ] ]
  )
}

transformHeadings()
```

I'm getting the following error, though:

```
/home/alex/node/es6/index.js:7
  for (let [regex, replacement] of replacementArray) {
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

I'm not sure why this is happening since `replacementArray` is effectively an array inside the `transformHeadings` function.

*Note: I'm using [io.js](https://iojs.org).*

Comment: Have you been able to use destructuring assignment in Node in other code? *edit* - V8 bug: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=811

Comment: According to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, destructuring is not supported in Node yet.

Comment: You seem a bit light on semicolons, too...

Comment: As you can see from the above link, io.js doesn't support destructuring either.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have not been successful in using a `let` inside of a `for` with array comprehension.  Consider the following example:

```
var arr=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

for([a,b] of arr) {
    console.log(a+b);
}
```

I have had great success once the `let` is removed.  This produces the expected output:

```
3
7
11
```

Comment: It didn't work. It says that `of` is an `Unexpected identifier`.